# HTTP Header Vary - Order of values

Tags: http, http-headers, cdn, http-caching, vary

We serve files for our websites to which we add CORS headers. The Vary header is required for cache management at the CDN and browser level.

So the question: is there any importance in the order of the values in this header?

```
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Accept-Encoding
```

An application at one of our CDN providers adds a Vary header in addition to ours. This results in the following:

```
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Accept-Encoding
```

We know that we can declare it multiple times according to the RFCs; the concern is what happens to the order of the elements for this parameter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. `Vary` means the cached response should only be used if the value of all listed headers matches. (To quote [the RFC](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#header.vary), *"... cache recipients ... MUST NOT use this response to satisfy a later request unless the later request has the same values for the listed fields as the original request ... In other words, Vary expands the cache key required to match a new request to the stored cache entry."*) There is no meaningful way to involve the order or priority of headers in that condition.